# Make ssh client process end once the connection to server was lost!

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, connectivity

I have a `ssh` process hanging around (i.e., does not exit and end). 
I can test that no connection with the `sshd` server exists anymore

```
ss -t | grep [SERVERIP]
```

yields no results. Additionally, being on the ssh server console I can also see that the client is not connected.

My question is having those aspects.

1. Is it really normal that a ssh client process does not end given the connection has ended.
2. In any case is there a setting with 
   `openssh-client` to please simply end once the connection has not been lost (i.e. temporary loss of connection, should cause a reconnection, but once that fails I wish the `ssh` client to end, so that the containing script/service can continue)
3. Assuming that (1) would not be normal is there a way to investigate why this `ssh` client process does not exit?

Facts:

- Knowing that the `ssh` client process runs still

  ```
  root@box$> ps -ef | grep ssh
  root        5106       1  0 12:06 pts/3    00:00:00 ssh -L 127.0.0.1:33339:127.0.0.1:33337 server /bin/noopsleep
  ```
- Check that there is no connection left

  ```
  root@box$> ss -t | grep [SERVERIP]
  root@box$>
  ```

Comment: 1. yes it's normal. 2. yes, run the ssh client with `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30` (look into the `ssh_config(5)` manpage for all possible combos). 3. 1. is normal.

Comment: @mosvy indeed I have set this option and also for savety specified `-o ServerAliveCountMax=3` (even thought it should be default), after having read what you suggested. Anyway I would be glad to know what goes on behind the scene. I fail to perceive how `ssh` stays arround while the `TCP` connection is not there anymore. I have attemped to simulate a TCP connection being interrrupted via killing the `sshd` serverside but this actually was noticed on the `ssh`. Any Idea how to simulate the TCP connection loss in a way as to test-drive the ServerAliveInterval option you suggest?

Comment: The simplest way to test is to unplug the cable between the server and the client. If the server has the `ClientAliveInterval` setting on, it will simply "disconnect" the client after a while, but the client has no way to know that it has been disconnected. Killing the sshd server does not work, because the kernel closes all file descriptors when a process is killed, and in the case of a socket that means interacting with the other end to do all the connection tear-up required by tcp (or other protocol).

Comment: @mosvy so unpluging the cable would work (would it be different to disabling the network device?? might be disabling the device would gracefully or differently end the backgrouding TCP connection? in other words it has to be cable out for simulation?)

Comment: A soft way to simulate it would be to drop the ssh packets from iptables or other firewall. Bringing the interface down most probably works too, but I'm not 100% sure.